# Plaid with Stripte PRODUCT_NOT_READY 400 Error

Tags: node.js, authentication, stripe-payments, webhooks, plaid

I used ACH transfer with plaid and stripe my website.

Bank connections are currently working. However, after connecting their bank account, the user gets a 400 server error that prevents them from being redirected to the dashboard.

I believe the error code associated with this issue is PRODUCT_NOT_READY
https://plaid.com/docs/errors/assets/#product_not_ready.

The server is a node server.
I want to know how I can fix this error.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you tracking the webhook? It seems that the server will send you a WebHook to the endpoint and only after that the resource will be available.

The Plaid server will send you a PRODUCT_READY webhook before you can call /asset_report/get

Answer (score 0):

The PRODUCT_NOT_READY error you linked to is of type ASSET_REPORT_ERROR. If you're using Plaid for ACH transfers, you're probably not using Assets and you're probably getting the PRODUCT_NOT_READY error of type ITEM_ERROR.  For that error, the likely causes listed are:

/transactions/get was called before the first 30 days of transaction data could be pulled. [Not relevant to you if you're not using transactions]

/auth/get was called on an Item that hasn't been verified, which is possible when using micro-deposit based verification [probably the cause of your problem]

Like Nikolas L. says, you will need to listen for webhooks, in this case to be alerted when the Item has been verified.